Arduino Bi-stable solenoid valve
I'm making a bi-stable solenoid valve with the help of an Arduino and a motor controller module (MX1508/MX1616). I saw many instructions about motor controller with PWM speed etc, but didn't see any guides about bi-stable solenoids.
I want the solenoid to OPEN for a minute and then CLOSE it. Can I use two digitalWrite function to open and close the valve instead of using the analog pins with PWMs? If so, then how long/delay should the input to change the state? I saw a description saying "pulse width=30ms".  I did not understand what that means, is it 30ms for delay for logic input?



You can control a bi-stable solenoid valve using digital pins on an Arduino and a motor controller module like the MX1508/MX1616. The "pulse width" you mentioned refers to the duration of the pulse needed to change the state of the solenoid. In your case, if the pulse width is 30ms, it means that you need to apply a signal to the solenoid for at least 30 milliseconds to ensure it switches states reliably.

@liaifat85 Thank you. Using digital pins makes the work a lot easier.

You need to switch fairly high-current, so you need some MOSFETs (or Bipolar transistors). You need to drive with both polarities, so you need an H-Bridge. H-Bridges are often Pulse-Width Modulated, but they don't have to be.
You don't want to drive the coils continuously, 30 mS pulses are sufficient to switch the state. Driving them continuously may damage them.
Note that many of these require water pressure to switch states. Since the working pressure doesn't go down to zero, this is probably the case for this one.
You can buy H-bridge modules that have a driver chip and 4 MOSFETs.
Use two GPIOs to source the pulses. You only want to pulse one at a time. The driver chip will almost always have a lock-out to prevent damage if you do drive both. One GPIO will create a positive pulse to the valve. The other GPIO will create a negative pulse to the valve.

I'm using a MX1508 controller module. I think they have a dual H bridge integrated with built-in thermal protection circuit and a common conduction circuit.   [1]: https://components101.com/modules/mx1508-dc-motor-driver-pinout-features-datasheet

Let's a I'm using Input 1 and Input 2. First I do Input 1 to HIGH and input 2 to LOW for solenoid to Open. After 1 minute I will do Input 1 to LOW and input 2 to HIGH to Close. Will this work?

@Kokachi - yes, except only drive HIGH for 30 mS.

Yes, I understand.
